# Trying MySQL On Internet

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a MySQL database with PhpMyAdmin and extracted it to my *www* folder. My PHP Code is

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "gultekin";
    $password = "20Rp3855";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=denemevt", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }


     ?>
```

Then I opened it using my browser locally;

*http://localhost:8080/vtdeneme/baglan3.php*

It works properly, and the "Connected successfully" writes on screen.

Then I uploaded my *baglan3.php* and MySQL database to my website (Using Filezilla). However, when I enter my website this warning message appears:

> "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'gultekin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

My password and username is correct (because it was working on my computer)

What can be the reason for that error?

Comment: It's a different computer! Why would the username and password for the database server be the same?!

Comment: localhost is your local computer, and you set the username/password combination to a certain value. I don't expect, that your provider gave you the same credetials. If the server is yours, then add username/password combination in mysql and reload it. If you got the account from a hoster, then create a user or use the given ones.

Comment: You need to reconfigure your database connections with respect to the configurations used in the domain in which you hosted your website.

Comment: Sorry, iam so new on php. Should i use the username and password which i use to connect my website?

Comment: @Caravansary it might be, or it could be different. It depends on how the DB was set up on the server. Or perhaps the issue may be that the DB has not yet been configured with username/password yet.

Comment: Thx for sharing your password..

Comment: Yes. Now change your username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolves to the default destination if you omit the `host=$servername`

Or try to get the value from the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable.

Assuming the mysql server is the same server the file is in then the code should look like this:

```
$servername = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$username = "gultekin";
$password = "20Rp3855";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=denemevt", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading your file baglan3.php and MySQL database to your website you have to change your code where metioned localhost to "the name of server that your hosting provider given".